# MultipartFile + Dto: как принять в одном запросе?

Tags: java, spring, multipart

Всем привет. Мне необходимо принять в одном запросе 2 файла - `MultipartFile` и информацию о нём в `DTO (JSON)`.

После гугления сделал так:

```
@PostMapping(produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<ImageTableDto> save(@RequestPart("data") ImageTableDto dto,
                                              @RequestPart("image")MultipartFile file) {
        return service.save(dto, file).map(d -> new ResponseEntity<>(d, HttpStatus.OK))
                .orElseGet(() -> new ResponseEntity<>(ResponseEntityUtils.createHeaders(), HttpStatus.OK));
    }
```

В постмане отправляю следующим образом:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если я отправлю один `MultipartFile` и буду принимать только его, то запрос гарантированно пройдёт. С добавлением текстового поля в виде JSON плюёт `400 Bad Request`. Подскажите, как решить эту задачу?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задача решилась самым неожиданным образом.

Для того, чтобы отправить `JSON` в формате `multipart/mixed` (так называется способ отправки файл + JSON), необходимо положить `JSON` в файл и отправить вторым файлом в формате `data.json`